# Scipy.stats.mvn.mvndst function for 3d inputs

Tags: python, multivariate-normal-distribution, scipy

I have some code that I'm trying to convert from working with floats to numpy arrays for performance reasons.  I have it down to one last function, which is below and requires the `mvn.mvndst` function from `scipy.stats`.  After some digging, it looks like the function is written in Fortran (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/stats/mvndst.f), but I'm wondering if there's another option to get this to work with numpy.

Here's the original code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mvn


def cbnd(a, b, rho):
    lower = np.array([0, 0])
    upper = np.array([a, b])
    infin = np.array([0, 0])
    correl = rho
    error, value, inform = mvn.mvndst(lower, upper, infin, correl)
    return value

# this works

a = 1
b = 1
rho = 1

cbnd(a, b, rho)


# this does not work

a = np.arange(0,1,step=0.1)
b = np.arange(0,1,step=0.1)
rho = np.arange(0,1,step=0.1)

cbnd(a, b, rho)
```

The last part gives this error:

```
ValueError: failed in converting 2nd argument `upper' of _mvn.mvndst to C/Fortran array
```

A few things I tried were:

- Matching the shape of `lower` and `infin` to the shape of `upper` with `a` and `b` as arrays.
- Transposing the above in various ways
- List comprehension (still fairly slow)

I did see this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html but I'm not really sure how to apply that compared to `mvn.mvndst`.

Any help is appreciated.